# How to download image in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, imagedownload, react-image

I use this to download -

```
<a href={`${link}`} download="file">Download</a>
```

But it's not working for me. I use the Chrome browser. It just opens the file in the browser.

Comment: What is the `Content-Disposition` header that is shown for the GET response in the dev tools? The [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) show some information about the `download` attribute behavior and how it is influenced by the header info.

Answer (score 1):

```
function download(fileUrl, fileName) {
 let a = document.createElement("a");
 a.href = fileUrl;
 a.setAttribute("download", fileName);
 a.click();
}
```

Comment: tried but not working.

Comment: check this - https://okywk.csb.app/

Comment: It's working for me too. But I am trying to do that when I click the download button automatically download the image instead of showing the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding target="_blank":

```
<a href={`${link}`} download="file" target="_blank" >Download</a>
```

Comment: its just opening the image on new tab. Its not downloading the image.